# change the footnote's length (increase footnotes right margin)

Tags: footnotes

I'm using Book (KOMA-Script), By default, the footnote runs roughly from left margin to the right margin of the page, I used the following to control the left margin:

```
\deffootnote[8em]{8em}{8em} {\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}
```

Result is as following:

[image: right margin]

I wondered if there is a way to control the right margin of the footnote? or in another word, the length of the footnote itself? i.e. 2em spacing to the right margin of the page?

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: I'm using Book (KOMA-Script).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really mean `2em` from the right margin of the *page*?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\deffootnote[8em]{8em}{8em} {\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\org@makefntext}{%
  \let\org@makefntext\@makefntext
  \renewcommand*{\@makefntext}{%
    \ifthispageodd{%
      \setlength{\hsize}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\oddsidemargin-1in-2em}%
    }{%
      \setlength{\hsize}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\evensidemargin-1in-2em}%
    }%
    \org@makefntext
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] Hello\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
world.\footnote{\lipsum[3]} \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

> [image: 2em to the right margin of the page]

If you have meant `2em` to the right margin of the text body, then the redefinition of `\@makefntext` simplifies to:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\deffootnote[8em]{8em}{8em} {\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\org@makefntext}{%
  \let\org@makefntext\@makefntext
  \renewcommand*{\@makefntext}{%
    \addtolength{\hsize}{-2em}%
    \org@makefntext
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] Hello\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
world.\footnote{\lipsum[3]} \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

> [image: 2em to right margin of text body]

Comment: How can this be achieved while using the `article` class?

Comment: `\deffootnote` and `\isthispageodd` are features of `KOMA-Script`, but the trick with the redefinition of `\@makefntext` and setting `\hsize` remains the same for class `article`.

Comment: Its ok. I figured it out. I will delete my comments. If you can as well.

Comment: amazing, works like a charm. thanks so much!