# Control position of footnote block with reledmac footnotes

Tags: footnotes, width, reledmac

I've got sample code that produces the following two-column footnote apparatus using the reledmac package. What I'm wondering is how I would manage to shift the entire footnote block over by a pre-determined amount. In the photo below, I show the existing document, with red vertical lines indicating where I'd like to shift the footnote block.
[image]

I can see with the reledmac package that I can easily modify the width of the entire footnote block with the `\widthX` command. Similarly, I can control the width of the two individual columns, and the separation between them. Also, I can indent the notes with `\parindentX`. However, I don't see how to control the actual amount of this indent.

What would be the simplest way to control the positioning of the footnote block such that it covers the bounds shown in the sample image?

The sample code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=5.5in]{geometry}
\geometry{includehead,nofoot,twoside,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=1in,right=1in,marginparwidth=3em,marginparsep=0.2ex}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\colalignX[A]{\RaggedRight}
\hsizetwocolX[A]{0.48\hsize}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}

\begin{document}

\footnoteA{First footnote}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look as if there is an interface but it should work if you redefine the balancing command. For the best effect the inserted space should be half of the difference between \hsize and the column widths.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=5.5in]{geometry}
\geometry{includehead,nofoot,twoside,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=1in,right=1in,marginparwidth=3em,marginparsep=0.2ex}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\colalignX[A]{\RaggedRight}
\hsizetwocolX[A]{0.45\hsize}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\rigidbalance}[3]{%
  \setbox0=\box#1 \@k=#2 \@h=#3%
  \@@line{\splittopskip=\@h \vbadness=\@M \hfilneg
  \hspace{0.05\hsize}%<-------------------
  \valign{##\vfil\cr\dosplits}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\footnoteA{First footnote\hfill xxx}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote\hfill xxx}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote\hfill xxx}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote\hfill xxx}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote\hfill xxx}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote\hfill xxx}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote\hfill xxx}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote\hfill xxx}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.
\footnoteA{First footnote\hfill xxx}Now is \footnoteA{Second footnote}the time \footnoteA{Third footnote}for all \footnoteA{Fourth footnote}good men \footnoteA{Fifth footnote}to come \footnoteA{Sixth footnote\hfill bla}to the \footnoteA{Seventh footnote}aid of their country.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ulrike and marquinho, thanks to both of you for your assistance! Ulrike's redefinition of \rigidbalance does accomplish what I set out to do. I've marked it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I can only offer a partial answer.

**The good news:** the *right* margin of the footnote block is already where you want it to be.

**The bad news:** I believe that `reledmac` in its current form does not provide readily accessible tools to customize the *left* margin. And because `reledmac` footnotes are specially defined, [a vanilla (or KOMAscript) approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75018/) won't work here.

It might be worth submitting a feature request with the [maintainer](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac).

### Right margin

Removing all unnecessary bits, and tinkering with the footnote text (`\hfill`) in order to use up all the available width and to reveal the whole extent of the footnote block, we get the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a6paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\hsizetwocolX[A]{0.48\hsize}

%\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\colalignX[A]{\RaggedLeft} % irrelevant: only affects the content of individual footnotes

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\onefootnote}{\footnoteA{A line-filling note \hfill$\rightarrow$\textbar}}

\newcommand{\sevenfootnotes}{\onefootnote Now is \onefootnote 
the time \onefootnote for all \onefootnote good men \onefootnote 
to come \onefootnote to the \onefootnote aid of their country. }

\sevenfootnotes \sevenfootnotes \sevenfootnotes
\sevenfootnotes \sevenfootnotes \sevenfootnotes
\end{document}
```

[image: a two-column footnote block that uses up all the page width]

The footnote block is already using all the text width, **up to the right margin**, so no need to shift anything to the right.

### Left margin: indentation?

However, I couldn't find a way to indent the entire block on the left.

You mention the setting `\parindentX[A]` (`reledmac` manual, [§ 7.8](https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/reledmac.pdf#page=49)), which indents the beginning of every new footnote (including the mark) as a potential workaround.

Indeed, it seems promising at first, but it has several issues (see the picture below):

- `\parindentX[A]` indents *all* footnotes, including those in the *right* column; and `reledmac` doesn't have a way (that I know of) to reduce the column separator and offset this undesired indentation.
- This command only affects the *first line* of a footnote: in longer footnotes, the following lines will start from the left margin. You'd need a "hanging indentation"; unfortunately the `reledmac` command `\hangindentX` (again, [§ 7.8](https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/reledmac.pdf#page=49)) only works with footnotes in `normal` arrangement, not the `paragraph` arrangement or columns.
- `\parindentX[A]` uses the same value of `\parindent` as the document at large. You cannot choose the ideal value for your footnote block (let's say `\setlength{\parindent}{8pt}`) without affecting the indentation of regular paragraphs in the *entire document*.

Try adding the following lines to the MWE:

```
\parindentX[A]
\setlength{\parindent}{8pt}
\hangindentX{8pt}   % with "twocol" notes, this doesn't come to bear
```

[image: an illustration of the problems with using parindentX]

### Left margin: apparatus width?

To be fair, `reledmac` does have a command to set the width of the footnote block: `\widthX` (manual, [§ 7.12.7](https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/reledmac.pdf#page=53)).

However, as of now, it is unhelpful in your case, because (in the LTR setting) *it only affects the right margin* of the footnote block, not the left. So you can cut off (or add) some length off the right margin, but not the left. For instance, via

```
\widthX{\columnwidth-3em}
```

[image: you can cut some length off the right margin, not the left]

I believe the additional possibility to edit the left margin of the footnote block would be a nice addition to `\widthX`. Do consider submitting a request with the maintainer of `reledmac` (and feel free to use these MWEs!)

Comment: Thank you for researching this. I believe your conclusion is correct, so I am going to submit a feature request to the maintainers.

Comment: @JeffDodson IMO, Ulrike's new answer should now be the accepted one :)