# Reledmac - Different margins for text and apparatus?

Tags: geometry, reledmac

I am typesetting a critical edition with Reledmac. Since I'm using the side margins for some comments, I have used the Geometry package to free up a good amount of space on both sides. Of course there's no reason for the apparatus to respect these same margins - is there a way to allow it to use a larger chunk of the sides of the page compared to the text?
Thanks in advance!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\geometry{top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.9in, right=1.9in, footskip=35pt}
    \usepackage{reledmac}
    \begin{document}
    \numberpstarttrue 
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
    Text \edtext{with its margins}{\Afootnote{I wish I could have different margins here}}
    \pend
    \endnumbering
    \end{document}
```

Comment: We had a similar question come up recently, but to the best of my knowledge there isn't a good solution *if your document has the setting `twoside`*. `reledmac` provides a command `\Xwidth` that can shift the **right** border of the footnote block – so far, so good. However you'd need to adjust the **outer** border, because that's where the marginal notes are. On half of the pages the outer margin is realized on the **left**, not the right, and `\Xwidth` doesn't help. See [Control position of footnote block with reledmac footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/675609/203961).

Comment: To see for yourself, try adding `\widthX{\textwidth+1in}` to the preamble.